# SQL Server stored procedure : return first and last date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures

Basically I'm going to pass in these multiselect values to my stored procedure:

```
'April 2016, May 2016, June 2016, July 2016'
```

Values could be more than 4.

Just how do I return the first and last date of the list using the stored procedure?

Expected output like:

```
2016-04-01 
2016-07-31
```

Comment: You can put them in a temp table and retrieve `min` and `max`. Why would you be needing this though?

Comment: you could pass them in using a TABLE VALUED PARAMETER - then it is easy to query the Table Valued Parameter using SQL (SQL SERVER 2008 and above)

Comment: find a split function, then just return MAX() and MIN().  Make sure the date format can be converted into date, otherwise you'll be using sting comparisons and not date comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert all your rows in temp table and find min and max dates do this in your procedure. if you are passing as comma-separated list make sure it should be converted to rows.

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Apr 2016') date_v
    INTO   #t11
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'may 2016')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'june 2016')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'july 2016')

    SELECT Min(date_v) min_date,
           Max(date_v) max_date
    FROM   #t11
```

Update:
I believe you are passing as comma separated list
for this follow below approach

```
      DECLARE @TOKENS VARCHAR(MAX)='AUG 2016,APR 2016'
DECLARE @list XML

SELECT @list = Cast('<a>' + Replace(@tokens, ',', '</a><a>')
                    + '</a>' AS XML)

SELECT Ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)'))AS data
INTO   #tr
FROM   @list.nodes('/a') AS x(t)

SELECT Min(CONVERT(DATETIME, data)),
       Max(CONVERT(DATETIME, data))
FROM   #tr
```

Updated Post with `EOMONTH` for max date

```
 declare @tokens varchar(max)='aug 2016,apr 2016'
declare @list xml

select @list = cast('<a>' + replace(@tokens, ',', '</a><a>')
                    + '</a>' as xml)

select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)'))as data
into   #tr1 
from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)

select min(convert(datetime, data)),
       eomonth((max(convert(datetime, data))))
from   #tr1
```

Comment: It is a multi select field, so parameters could be more than 4

Comment: @user3543512 Updated post please check.

Comment: Your method works great. But the Max date I've got is 1 AUG 2016, it should be 31 AUG 2016

Comment: It says eomonth is not a valid function

Comment: @user3543512 which sql server version you are using?

Comment: @user3543512 Replace eomonth expresiion with dateadd(mm,1,max(convert(datetime, data)))-1 this will work. Error is because you may using sql server below than 2012 version

Answer (score 1):

try this one -

1 it changes to XML,

2 reads from XML document,

3 changes text to dates (hopefully! may be system dependency there)

4 selects min and max, converts to last day of month on max

5 displays in date order

```
declare @list nvarchar(max) = 'April 2016, May 2016, June 2016, July 2016';

DECLARE @XML nvarchar(max) = '<nub><rec><dat>' + REPLACE(@list, ',', '</dat></rec><rec><dat>') + '</dat></rec></nub>';

select @xml;

DECLARE @iX INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @ix output, @xml;


WITH CTE AS (SELECT CAST('01 ' + dat AS DATETIME) dat_sort ,dat dat  FROM OPENXML(@ix, '//rec', 2) 
WITH (dat varchar(50))),
MIND AS (select MIN(dat_sort) M from cte UNION SELECT dateadd(day, -1,dateadd(month, 1, MAX(dat_sort))) M from cte)
SELECT M from MIND ORDER BY M

--this is needed to avoid memory leak
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @iX
```

Comment: No, it could be more than 4.

Comment: if it could be any number - how are you passing them?  As XML for example?  Or will they be in a table or a string of some type?

Comment: you could pass them in using a TABLE VALUED PARAMETER - then it is easy to query the Table Valued Parameter using SQL